# Freeware Colordialog Control for .Net

Tags: c#, .net, controls, colordialog

anybody know any .Net freeware control for color selection (color dialog) that supports RGB, HSL and CMYK color models.

I'm looking for something like this.

[image] [image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly the same, but a very good color picker I found was at CodeProject. I use this one without problems in one of my applications:

http://beta.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/colorwheelv1.aspx

These two support all the three color models you want:

http://beta.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/adobe_cp_clone_part_1.aspx
http://beta.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/ZetaColorEditor.aspx

Although the first is better looking and is better in functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This things are too specialized to be in the open. But you can take a look at [Paint.net sources](http://www.afterdawn.com/software/source_codes/paint.net.cfm) for at least HSV color wheel and other color-related utility classes and functions. Old versions (I've linked to 3.05) are under MIT license and you can borrow code from there.